# Can't change gridview itemssource

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, itemsource

I'm trying to change a box's color in a gridview(that has ItemTemplates which has 100 green boxes).

First, I created a list(which typed as my class) and I added all items to list and I added list to my gridview source :

```
grid1.ItemsSource = boxlist;
```

After, I added a click event for item click on gridview. I want that when I clicked to an item, this item's color will be changed. So I edited list as it :

```
int id = ((Boxes)e.ClickedItem).id;
boxlist[id].color = "DarkRed";
grid1.ItemsSource = boxlist;
```

I tried it to change color of clicked item but it doesn't work. Color of list item is changing succesfully but gridview is not taking it. But I want that gridview takes this new source. How can I solve this problem?

My class :

```
class Boxes
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

XAML of GridView

```
<GridView x:Name="grid1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="354,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" Height="650" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="grid1_ItemClick">
        <GridView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
                <Grid Height="50" Width="50">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rect1" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="{Binding color}" Tag="{Binding id}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.Resources>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataTemplate1"/>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Comment: Are you doing this in WPF? WinForms?
- Can you provide the ItemTemplate you are using and the Gridview XAML? 
- You need to use an ObservableCollection instead of List so that the UI will be notified with the changes in the Collection.

Comment: I am doing it in XAML.

Comment: I changed List to ObservableCollection but it has samething. Still can't update.

Comment: Please show us the xaml code.

Comment: I added gridview's xaml code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to null the ItemSource just before you set the new value:

```
ctlList.ItemsSource = null;
ctlList.ItemsSource = YourObjects;
```

I recommand to use DataContext and Binding instead of your solution:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples

Comment: Actually I saw your post before times but when I set null and re-set to list again, It takes some while so it is not fast.

grid1.Items does not contains any method like "Refresh".

Comment: That is the only solution in your case. What do you mean when you say "it is not fast"? How large is your list?

Comment: No. I mean that when you clear a list and refill all items, it takes a while. You can try in visual studio. Try your answer and see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DataContext instead like this:

```
grid1.DataContext = boxlist;
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work. When I do it, I can't see any item in my gridview.